tooltip in ckeditor 4.24?
How do you add tooltips to ckeditor 4.24? I checked the tooltip function in ckeditor 4.24, but I did not find anything about it.
Eg: When I hover over a link, I want to see the tooltip for it.
I tried to use custom tooltips using CSS but was unable to achieve the desired result.
